# Multiple indices with biblatex and indexing

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I need two indices: one of names, one of concepts.

I'm using `biblatex` with indexing (and TeXshop on a mac, I am a newbie of LaTeX, so sorry for any stupid question). 
This works fine for the index of names, but I need to index also concepts.

Until now, I did with `\index{concept1}`. I get one index with both names and concepts. This was fine until my supervisor wanted two different indices.

Now, with the code below, I get only one index of things I manually indexed, but no more names from `biblatex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
headinclude,,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
           numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
           tablecaptionabove]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,indexing,hyperref,square,natbib,backref]{biblatex}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=title,title={List of Titles}]



\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
\ifciteindex
{\indexnames{labelname}}%
{}}
\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
\ifbibindex
{\indexnames{author}%
\indexnames{editor}%
\indexnames{editora}%
\indexnames{editorb}%
\indexnames{editorc}}%
{}}%
%\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
%\usebibmacro{index:title}{\index}{#1}}
%\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
%\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[nomi]}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}
\usepackage{index}
%\newindex{default}{idx}{ind}{Index}
%\newindex{nomi}{ndx}{nnd}{Index of Names}


\usepackage{makeidx} %\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{}{}{}


\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis} %minionpro parts
\usepackage{arsclassica}


\input{arsclassica-settings}

\makeindex%[program=xindy]

\begin{document}


\input{Chapters/hw}
 \index{normativity}

\printbibliography

\printindex
%\printindex[title]

\end{document}
```

I hope to have provided a MWS – I suspect I must run twice something I don't know.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I took the liberty of doing minor edits on your post; we like to [mark our inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) here. You can use backticks `\`` to obtain the same result as in my edit.

Comment: You surely cannot use both `imakeidx` and `index`.

Comment: Can you show the version with only one index that worked?

Comment: Example 21 from the biblatex documentation covers multiple indices (concept/subject, name, title) with the `index` package. The answer really depends on the indexing package you're using, so I'd meet egreg's request.

Comment: Now there is the version with only one index working, both of names and of concepts.

Comment: @Fedrîg You're loading three different indexing packages here (`imakeidx`, `index` and `makeidx`), but you only need one of them. I provided an answer demonstrating use with `imakeidx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 21 from the `biblatex` documentation (`21-indexing-multiple.tex`) demonstrates how you can create separate subject, name and title indices using the `index` package. Here is another example using the `imakeidx` package. It compiles with the usual calls to `latex` and `biber` (or `bibtex`, if you load `biblatex` with `backend=bibtex`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,
  headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,
  captions=tableheading]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,indexing,hyperref,square,natbib,backref]{biblatex}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,
  listings]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\makeindex[title={Concept Index}]
\makeindex[name=name,title={Name Index}]
\makeindex[name=title,title={Title Index}]

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name]}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[title]}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{author}%
     \indexnames{editor}%
     \indexnames{editora}%
     \indexnames{editorb}%
     \indexnames{editorc}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\cite{piccato,gaonkar,jaffe,malinowski,coleridge,gerhardt,cicero}
\index{Example concept index entry}
\printbibliography
\printindex
\printindex[name]
\printindex[title]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now, but the last page of each index won't print, and the margins of odd/even pages are inverted. I get these kinds of errors: `\begin{document} ended by \end{theindex}` and `\begin{document} ended by \end{multicols}`

Comment: @Fedrîg That is related to your document layout, not biblatex. I don't get any issues on my end when I use your document class, load `subfig` and your additional packages. So the problems must lie in the files you include with `\input`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer worked for me, though it needs to be updated as explained in [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/biblatex-3-3-name-formatting):

> In biblatex 3.3. the format of \DeclareNameFormat has changed. In its code part it no longer accepts 8 arguments, but only one. For the various parts of a name there are now macros which you get by splitting the main name data with \namepart.

I updated the MWE accordingly:

```
documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,
  headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,
  captions=tableheading]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,indexing,hyperref,square,natbib,backref]{biblatex}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,
  listings]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\makeindex[title={Concept Index}]
\makeindex[name=name,title={Name Index}]
\makeindex[name=title,title={Title Index}]

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name]}%
  {\namepartfamily}% #1->\namepartfamily, #2->\namepartfamilyi
  {\namepartgiven}%  #3->\namepartgiven,  #4->\namepartgiveni
  {\namepartprefix}%  #5->\namepartprefix, #6->\namepartprefixi
  {\namepartsuffix}%   #7->\namepartsuffix, #8->\namepartsuffixi
  }   

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[title]}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{author}%
     \indexnames{editor}%
     \indexnames{editora}%
     \indexnames{editorb}%
     \indexnames{editorc}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\cite{piccato,gaonkar,jaffe,malinowski,coleridge,gerhardt,cicero}
\index{Example concept index entry}
\printbibliography
\printindex
\printindex[name]
\printindex[title]
\end{document}
```

As asked by Mensch, I add screenshots of the results:

[image: The body of the text]

[image: The bibliography]

[image: Concept Index]

[image: Name Index]

[image: Title Index]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an screenshot of your resulting pdf?

Comment: Many thanks! I added screenshots of the different sections, but it may be too much. Since the interest was in several things, how would you suggest presenting them?